# Why Play requires an exploded WAR?

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, playframework

I'm looking for away to integrate play in and an fairly old application stack: J2EE, Tomcat6 etc. I know that the JEE deployment is a second class feature in Play but I still want to consider it at least.

One of the issues is the requirement to use exploded wars. Do you know why is it needed? Most of the clients I work for require packaged .war archives to make it easy to deploy, so this restriction could be an early show stopper.

Answer (score 0):

Why is a war easier?  With a war you need to set a bunch of config up on a server..

with the default zip, you unzip and run. Seems easier.

But regardless, there is a Play war plugin. Should get you fixed right up. See https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin/